# Clients for multiple clusters

Tags: ignite

What would be the best way for an application (Ignite client) to connect to 
multiple clusters?

For now, I can think of creating multiple Ignite client instances with 
different configuration for the application (within a single Java app).

Comment: Have you tried that? Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: I didn't say it will not work, I said that's only option I know. Was asking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Your described approach is sound. There aren't any alternatives to having multiple clients, (at least) one per cluster.